# Ошибка 3034 в EF WPF

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Столкнулся с ошибкой `3034: Проблема во фрагментах сопоставления, начиная со строк 89, 99:Две сущности с потенциально различными ключами сопоставлены с одной строкой. Убедитесь, что эти два фрагмента сопоставления обеспечивают сопоставление обоих конечных элементов набора AssociationSet с соответствующими столбцами.`

Честно признаться - совсем не понимаю суть ошибки, так как сопоставления данных все имеются...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы почитал про нормальные формы БД. Явно есть дублирование колонок в таблицах тичерс и студентс. Как минимум ФИО можно сливать в одну таблицу. Я бы сделал таблицу юзерс и сделал либо колонку who где рассматривал бы 2 варианта: тичер и студент, либо сделал отдельную таблицу Who, где через ИН в таблице юзерс определял бы кто он, а может быть и через смежную таблицу (для реализации отношения многие-ко-многим). Может учитель одновременно быть студентом? (а почему бы и нет?) - эта проблема будет решена. Далее принадлежность к группам и группам учителей также сделал бы через смежные таблицы.

Comment: Потом можно уже сделать связи и ограничения и только потом наполнять таблицы данными. В процессе наполнения станет ясно если вы что-то не туда попробуете добавить.